# #REF when deleting rows/columns in Excel-file for easier db-import

Tags: excel, vba, ref

I'm trying to change the data of an excel file for easier import into my database. I'm doing this with 3 pieces of macro code inside the excel.

Here are the code:

**1 - Delete the two first columns**

```
Sub Del_Columns ()

Columns ("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

**2 - Fill the right-most column with values of the above, end when new value.**

```
Sub FillBlanks()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim col As Long

Set wks = ActiveSheet
with wks

col = .Range("M").Column
Set rng = .UsedRange
LastRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(LastRow, col)) _ 
.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No Blanks Found"
Exit Sub

Else
rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End If

With .Cells(1, col).EntireColumn
.Value = .Value
End With
End With
End Sub
```

**3 - Delete all rows that have empty cells inside them (Taking col F as an example, for deleting the whole row when its empty. Which it Always is)**

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
On Error Resume Next
Columns ("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

**Summary**

*When doing this, im getting #REF on some of the cells, what should I do to prevent/fix this?*

**Also;** Is this code better for Number 2 (Fill cells with above value):

```
Sub FillCellsFromAbove()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
With Columns(1)
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
.Value = .Value

End With
Err.Clear
Application.Updating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example of code is better, but you did use a different formula style. Make sure you use `.FormulaR1C1` as you have in step 2 of your code.

The #REF error as almost certainly related to you deleting rows when you're referencing one above. You should consider looking for a different way to reference, or delete the rows you want to eliminate first, then create your formulas.

If that's not an option, and you're certain you ALWAYS want the cell to reference one row above it, you could use the Indirect excel function. It will slow down performance, but I think this is what you're trying to do.

Either `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` method will work in this case:

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=Indirect(""R[-1]C"",FALSE)"
```